# And YOU Get A Hat! is missing

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2017

From here, it says that I earned **And YOU Get A Hat!** hat

[image]

But it not present when I am about to wear it

[image]

The hat is not present, did I miss something?

**NOTE:**

- I waited a bit before posting thinking there's delay
- I specifically clicked its link just to make sure
- Looking [here](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) shows that I really earned the hat

[image]

Comment: https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/and-you-get-a-hat

Comment: @SurajRao Checked that, it says that I earned it in StackOverflow, or should I do something?

Comment: No..I see your hat https://stackoverflow.com/users/5597834/swellar#winter-bash .. maybe caching?

Comment: @SurajRao I tried using hard refresh, but still the same.

Comment: And now YOU don't get a hat!